# How can I restrict a function to make it only callable by one contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Assume I have two contracts as follows

```
contract FirstContract{

function anyFunction(){}

}

contract SecondContract{

  FirstContract x = new FirstContract();

function anotherFunction(){
  x.anyFunction(); ///////
}

}
```

How can I restrict `anyFunction()` so that only `SecondContract` can call it and nothing else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [modifiers](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#function-modifiers) to restrict access to a function by other contracts/users.

Example:

```
contract FirstContract {

    address creator; // This will be the address of SecondContract.

    function FirstContract() {
        creator = msg.sender; // Which we set here.
    }

    modifier onlyCreator() {
        require(msg.sender == creator); // If it is incorrect here, it reverts.
        _;                              // Otherwise, it continues.
    } 

    function anyFunction() onlyCreator {} // This can now only be accessed by SecondContract

}
```

If this is what you are looking for, you may also be interested in researching the more common `owned` pattern, which works similarly.

Comment: Cool, this answers my question. Is there any way I could limit which contracts can instantiate another contract? I tried putting the modifier on the constructor but it didn't work.

Comment: In theory, you could put that same code in the constructor without a modifier. In practice, there's no way to stop a sufficiently determined individual from creating an instance of a contract. If nothing else, he can just modify the code to allow it.

Comment: This doesn't work and it's a huge security risk, this shouldn't be the accepted answer, msg.sender is the original tx sender not the direct caller. In the call "user -> contract1 -> contract2" msg.sender is user not contract1

Comment: No. You are confusing tx.origin and msg.sender

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough rep to add comment. But just confirming the selected answer is correct and Enrique's comment is incorrect. User -> Contract1 ->Contract2, msg.sender IS contract 1 for contract2.

See here: [Who is msg.sender when calling a contract from a contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28972/who-is-msg-sender-when-calling-a-contract-from-a-contract/28977)

tx.origin is the EOA, msg.sender works for contract. [image]